# NSArray Memory Management

Tags: iphone

For some reason when I release the NSArray I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. Here is the implementation:

```
-(void) loadAllAlphabets
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 
    NSArray *imagesPath = [[NSArray alloc] init]; 

    imagesPath = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Images"];

    alphabets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

    NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc] init]; 

    for(int i=0; i<= imagesPath.count -1 ; i++) 
    {
        fileName = [[imagesPath objectAtIndex:i] lastPathComponent];
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:fileName];

        sprite.userData = [[fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension] uppercaseString];   

        [alphabets addObject:sprite]; 
    }

    // release fileName 
    [fileName release]; 
    fileName = nil; 

    [imagesPath release]; // this causes the application to crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
//  imagesPath = nil;
```

}

**UPDATE 1:**

So, the problem was that although I was responsible for releasing the imagesPath object since I used alloc that soon become irrelevant when pathsForResourcesOfType returned an autorelease object. 
This means I should not release the imagesPath object manually.

The following line should be used:

```
NSArray *imagesPath = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Images"];
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Another question which is related to this post. In the following code I initialize a new NSMutableArray manually.

```
alphabets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Later I insert CCSprite (Cocos2d objects) into alphabets array. CCSprite are autorelease objects. Do I still have to release alphabets manually? Since, after some time all objects are released and memory will be returned but then what will be left inside alphabets NSMutable array?

Comment: The leak occurs when you reassign imagesPath to the pathsForResourcesOfType: call, because you already allocated and i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

general rule of thumb in memory management - you should release an object only if you obtain it using method that contains new, copy or alloc in it (standard method follow that rule and you should stick to it as well).

In your case you obtain imagesPath object using `pathsForResourcesOfType:` method which returns an autoreleased object so you must not release it yourself.

**Edit:** yes, you need to release `alphabets` object somewhere (for the same reason - you got it with alloc method).

Objective-c containers take an ownership of objects added to them, that us when objects are added to an array they get retained so it is guaranteed that their life time is at least as long as the life time of container. When you remove object from collection or collection itself is destroyed then its members get released (to compensate retain on add).

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! So, even though I allocated the imagesPath the pathsForResourcesOfType returned an autorelease object which I must not release manually.

Answer (score 6):

I think the confusion is here:

```
NSArray *imagesPath = [[NSArray alloc] init]; 
imagesPath = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Images"];
```

The first line creates a new object. This object really needs to be released.

The second line over-writes that object with a new, self-managed object. This does *not* need to be manually release.

This means that you're leaking the first imagesPath.

In general, you need to release an object if you `alloc` or `copy` it. And you shouldn't over-write an object before you release (or autorelease) its content.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you are leaking memory as you initialize `imagesPath` with an empty non-mutable array and then discard it when you assign he result of `pathsForResources:` to it. Just do this instead:

```
NSArray *imagesPath = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Images"];
```

Same error with `fileName`. Not need to initialize it with an empty non mutable string.

And also do not release `fileName` since it is also an autoreleased object.

Comment: The reason fileName is autorelease object is because it comes from the imagesPath NSArray right?

Comment: Also, if I am running a loop and assigning fileName does that means I am creating new object of NSString for each loop count.

Comment: @azamsharp yes, the value from the line 'fileName = [[NSString alloc] init];' is discarded when you assign an autoreleased string to it inside a loop. Personally I'd initialize fileName with nil before loop

Comment: yes, you create a string object on each loop iteration, but those strings are autoreleased so runtime will dispose of them itself - you don't need to worry about them

Comment: I just created a NSString *fileName = nil outside the loop.